# Cannot start SonarQube service on windows 10

Tags: windows, service, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm having a problems while setting up service for SonarQube. I have tried everything I could but still I'm not able to fix this problem.
[This is the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO8wK.png). As you can see, I logged on using my administrator account (not Local System) [suggested by SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Windows) and many other posts here and there. **I installed Sonar successfully on my laptop using this method** but not be able to do that on my PC. Please help, my thanks in advance.

Comment: What, if anything, do your SonarQube logs say on the topic?

Comment: You mean when I install or start the service in the bin directory? I got this only: Unable to start the service - The service did not start due to a logon failure - Just like the image.

Comment: in mean in _$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/sonar.log_

Comment: Starting the SonarQube service...
Unable to start the service - The service did not start due to a logon failure. (0x42d)
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified.
Not sure that this helps...

Comment: Do you use a local database? Did you re-enter your admin password?

Comment: Sr for late respone, it was midnight by the time I asked. Yes I did use local database and I re-entered my admin password also.

Comment: I suggest to test version 5.6 which fixes https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7154. Note that final release will be published in the next few days but Release Candidate 2 is already available for testing.

Comment: does it work if you use `local system`??

Comment: @entre well, no it doesn't. Still trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thank you for all of your support, guest that it's all my fault when setting up my PC, didn't specify related information. Sorry for wasting your time on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple issues here.
First "Wrapper Started as Console Launching a JVM... Unable to execute Java command. The system cannot find the file specified" is telling you that you incorrectly set the wrapper.java.command property in wrapper.conf.

According to the screenshot, the service is not starting due to #1069 error, the initial cause can be due to multiple reason, incorrect password or Administrator does not have the right to start services, you may find the reason in the event viewer.